# A simple visual puzzle to die for

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, visual

Can you figure out how the patterns in the picture were generated, and determine what the hidden pattern at the bottom right should look like?

[image]

This is a visual puzzle, and the solution can be determined by simply looking at the image. But if you'd die for a hint, you might be on the right track.

Comment: Side note: this reminds me of a hand string game I used to play before, but it is obviously not it. :) http://www.stringfigures.info/cfj/figures/745.png

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe Ivo Beckers has the right answer but not for the intended reason. Rather, the idea is to

> take the faces of a die, in order 1-6, and for each one join the dots that are present to the positions where dots could be but aren't.

So, in particular,

> since the "1" and "6" faces are complements, they feature line segments from the central dot to the six positions present in the "6".

> [image: image of the pattern]

Comment: This is what I thought when I first saw the puzzle, but I couldn't make it work for some of the examples; I think I've figured out that my problem was a difference in expectations, explained [here](http://www.toddstrong.com/personalthoughts/dice_and_spots.php). Thought I'd mention it, in case anyone else is similarly stymied. Note that the link is a BIG hint if you don't want to be spoiled.

Answer (score 14):

It will look like this:

> [image]

Because in a single row you overlap the first two images and the third is the result of that, with double lines being removed.

Comment: Good observation! But we have to explain how all the other patterns were generated. Look at the hints in the puzzle.

Answer (score 7):

The missing figure is...

> ...the same as the first (top left) figure.

In each row, the middle figure shows...

> ...the differences between the figures on its left and right.

Comment: [Ivo Beckers got there first](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/43462/18129) by 51 seconds

Comment: Very good! Check my comment on @Ivo 's answer.

Comment: [Gareth McCaughan got there with both feet](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/43464/18129)

Answer (score 1):

If presence of line is 1 and absence of line is 0. And each row of figures is an equation than

> Figure 1 (Exclusive or or Exclusive disjunction) Figure 2 (Equals) Figure 3

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Could you expand on this answer a bit? I'm not quite sure how you get from "presence of line is 1 and absence of line is 0" to what's in the spoilertag.

Comment: This is the exactly same answer that Ivo Beckers and humn came up with, only expressed in mathematical jargon.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply an xor operation. Each straight line is a 1 and therefore they cancel. If there is a line in the left figure and no corresponding line in the right figure, the line remains and vice versa.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Can you explain why you think this is the answer? Answers without explanation are deleted.